# How to attach Kubernetes Service with a running Pod

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-service, fabric8, kubernetes-jobs

Here is my problem statement,

I started a Kubernetes Service (Svc-1) which then starts Kubernetes Job (Job-1) and that job create a Pod (Pod-1). This service (Svc-1) actually receives job status like ACTIVE, READY, FAIL, SUCCESS of the job.

Svc-1 -> Job-1 -> Pod-1

Now, for some reason this Service (Svc-1) goes down and Kubernetes starts a new service (Svc-2). Now this service Svc-2 is not monitoring the currently running Job and also it can't receive the events generated by Job-1.

Svc-1 (DOWN) ! Job-1 -> Pod-1

I want to attach the new Service (Svc-2) to the running job so I could receive the events generated by the Job's Pod and record that in the database.

Svc-2 -> Job-1 -> Pod-1

**Service File**

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: svc-dev
    
      labels:
        app: svc-dev
    
    spec:
      type: ClusterIP
      selector:
        app: svc-dev
      ports:
        - name: http
          protocol: TCP
          port: 8080
```

**Fabric8 Java Code to create Kubernetes Job**

```java
    private JobDto createJob(KubernetesClient client, JobDto jobDto) throws JobExecutionException{
        try {
            MixedOperation<Job, JobList, ScalableResource<Job>> v1Job = client.batch().v1().jobs();
            Job kubernetesJob = v1Job.load(resource.getInputStream()).get();
            log.info("{} job has been loaded", jobType);

            //Set name for job
            kubernetesJob.getMetadata().setName(jobDto.getJobName());
            log.info("Set name for job {}",jobDto.getJobName());

            //Add label to job
            String executionType = jobDto.getExecutionType().name();
            Map<String, String> labels = MapUtils.of(LABEL1, jobType, LABEL2, executionType);
            kubernetesJob.getMetadata().setLabels(labels);
            log.info("Added labels for job {}", kubernetesJob.getMetadata().getLabels());

            //Add label to pod
            kubernetesJob.getSpec().getTemplate().getMetadata().setLabels(labels);
            log.info("Added labels for job pod template");

            //Add node selector role
            kubernetesJob.getSpec().getTemplate().getSpec().setNodeSelector(getNodeSelectorRole(jobType));
            log.info("Added NodeSelector for job pod template");

            //Add service account to job
            kubernetesJob.getSpec().getTemplate().getSpec().setServiceAccountName(config.getServiceAccount());
            log.info("Added ServiceAccountName for job pod template");

            //Add container configuration and volume is also mounted
            kubernetesJob.getSpec().getTemplate().getSpec().setContainers(getContainers(jobDto));
            log.info("Added Containers for job pod template");

            //Add Volume
            kubernetesJob.getSpec().getTemplate().getSpec().setVolumes(getVolumes());
            log.info("Added Volumes for job pod template");

            // Create Kubernetes Job
            v1Job.inNamespace(config.getNamespace()).resource(kubernetesJob).create();
            log.info("Created job with name {}",jobDto.getJobName());
            return jobDto;

        }catch(Exception exception ){

        }
    }
```

**Deployment File**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.application.name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.application.name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.application.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.application.name }}

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.application.name }}
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        role: {{ .Values.application.nodeSelectorRole }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.application.serviceAccountName }}
      serviceAccount: {{ .Values.application.serviceAccountName }}
      volumes:
        - name: {{ .Values.application.persistentVolume }}
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: {{ .Values.application.persistentVolumeClaim }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.application.name }}
          image: {{ .Values.application.image }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.application.imagePullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: {{ .Values.application.portname }}
              containerPort: {{ .Values.application.port }}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: {{ .Values.application.persistentVolume }}
              mountPath: {{ .Values.application.containerMountPath }}
```

Using Helm so `{{ .Values}}` are placeholders and will be replaced on runtime.

I am using Spring-Boot and fabric8 library.

Please guide me how can I achieve this.

Comment: what is your service, job, pod definition? how does your selector looks like in your service?

Comment: I have node selector configured in the out deployment file. I am creating job using fabric8 library.

Comment: did you make sure in your values.yaml file that .Values.application.name is set to svc-dev